# Celluloid deadlock during rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deadlock, celluloid

I have the following controller path that is supposed to upload a file to azure.

```
def do_upload(upload, container_name, path, name, data)
    Azure.config.storage_account_name = APP_CONFIG['ac_name']
    Azure.config.storage_access_key = APP_CONFIG['key']
    azure_blob_service = Azure::Blob::BlobService.new

    begin
      container = azure_blob_service.get_container_properties(container_name)
    rescue => error
      puts error
      upload.upload_failed = true
      upload.save
      render :body => nil, :status => 503 and return
    end

    begin
      azure_blob_service.create_block_blob(container.name, path + name, data, {chunking: true, timeout: 300})
    rescue => error
      puts error
      upload.upload_failed = true
      upload.save
      render :body => nil, :status => 503 and return
    end

    upload.number_of_files += 1 unless (params[:type] == 'thumbnail' || params[:type] == 'model')
    upload.save

    render json: { :status => 200 } and return
  end
```

Im using azure-contrib to upload the chunked file to azure and azure-contrib in turn uses Celluloid.

The error I get is:

```
I, [2016-10-24T11:42:15.290622 #65239]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
F, [2016-10-24T11:42:15.296640 #65239] FATAL -- :
F, [2016-10-24T11:42:15.312435 #65239] FATAL -- : fatal (No live threads left. Deadlock?):
F, [2016-10-24T11:42:15.312543 #65239] FATAL -- :
```

Comment: Yes it is Rails 5.

Comment: It seems to have been a bug in celluloid. reverting back to 0.16.0 solved this issue. I think the bug should be fixed in the next release. 0.17.4 but it is yet to be released.

Comment: There are also some new way that Rails5 will deadlock, if in typical development mode configuration with autoload, under concurrency. I was thinking perhaps you ran into one of them.